# Playwright projects are waiting for non-depency projects

Tags: playwright

I am using Playwright in TypeScript. I created a small example of my problem where I have the following projects in the playwright.config.ts file. All tests consist of a navigation and then a simple timeout to differentiate the duration of the tests.

```
projects: [
        {
            name: 'test A',
            testMatch: 'tests/testA.spec.ts'
        },
        {
            name: 'test B',
            testMatch: 'tests/testB.spec.ts',
            dependencies: ['test A']
        },
        {
            name: 'test C',
            testMatch: 'tests/testC.spec.ts',
            dependencies: ['test B']
        },
        {
            name: 'test D',
            testMatch: 'tests/testD.spec.ts',
            dependencies: ['test A']
        }
    ]
```

Given the dependencies between the projects, I expect that test A is run first, followed by tests B and D in parallel, and test C starts as soon as test B is finished. I set the tests up in such way that test D takes approximately 10s longer than test B.

When running the tests, I notice that test C does not start until both test B and D are finished. So test C essentially waits until test D is finished (since test B already finished 10s earlier) which it shouldn't do since there is no dependency between the projects.

Is there any way I can adjust the config file to make sure projects do not wait until non-dependency projects are finished running?

Comment: Timeouts aren't reliable

Comment: The timeouts I used to create the small working example do exactly what they should do

Comment: It may seem that way, until a test takes longer than expected, or the timeout runs longer than expected. They're imprecise, "best effort", so you can easily hit a situation where 1/100 runs, or 1/20 runs, or whatever, fails for no reason. Ordering in any browser automation or test suite should be event-driven, not timeout-guess-driven.

Comment: [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout): "Discouraged. Never wait for timeout in production. Tests that wait for time are inherently flaky. Use Locator actions and web assertions that wait automatically."

Comment: The question I asked is about the order the tests are run in and which tests should or should not wait for each other to finish. I understand what you say about timeouts but that is off topic here. I do not use timeouts in my actual tests, I simply used them here to create a small working example.